# What is the meaning of the subclause of 'goes off the deep end'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, clauses

If a real-time program **goes off the deep end**, the system can become unresponsive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of several idioms related to the dangers of deep water.  These include:

> **go off the deep end** - lose one's temper, act rashly or get carried away with something
>   **throw someone in at the deep end** - put someone in a challenging position without preparation
>   **in deep water** - in trouble, in a difficult situation

Your example doesn't quite fit the usual meaning of the idiom.  Presumably they mean that if a real-time program becomes overloaded or goes wrong it will make the system unresponsive.

Comment: I'm only familiar with your first definition of *go off the deep end*. To be honest I think OP's usage is either a localised idiom, or a misuse, but it's obvious enough what it's intended to mean.

Answer (score 2):

"Going off the deep end" just means going out of control. Synonyms are "going haywire", "going kablooey", and so on.